# VS Code | Hide file path in tab name

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know what I did or do but I'm pretty sure this wasn't there before. How do I get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by removing the line `"workbench.editor.labelFormat": "medium",` in `settings.json`.

You could also do set it to default `"workbench.editor.labelFormat": "default",`