# How to hide file path from the VSCode top bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I want to make my editor as minimal as possible and rely on shortcuts. So I've already hidden the tabs and breadcrumbs but It's still displaying the file path on the top. I just want to hide this.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code | Hide file path in tab name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73922083/vs-code-hide-file-path-in-tab-name)

Comment: @user What is the use of a comment saying: "I don't know how"

Comment: looks like the name of the tab, it displays the directory if you have multiple files open with the same name (at least in Windows), maybe on Mac it always displays directory

Comment: @HoàngHuyKhánh no that does not answer the question. that's about tab handles. this is after tab handles are already hidden.